# Problem with Localization of ContentTypes

Tags: content-type, localization

I've developed some content types. There are no resource files in my solution. When I'm deploying them to an English team site the description is correctly displayed. If I deploy them to a German team site the description is changed to the description of content type document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved the issue. When deploying via Visual Studio the problem occured. When deploying manually it didn't happen.